# unable to get login page after removing gtk3.0

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Gtk3.0 and Gtk2.0 are attached to one process in Jetson tx1. When I Googled I got that someone has solved removing GTK3. I did after that no luck i am unable to get my login page. Any help.

Comment: Have you tried troubleshooting this?

Comment: i tried editing the lightdm.conf file with "unity greeter" didn't work then installing gnome-shell didn't work.